# Replace white space with hyphens in Django URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I saw that a lot of websites (including stackoverflow) will have the title of the questions/articles in the URL with hyphens and I am trying to achieve the same for a small blog app using Django, however, so far I have been having 0 success.

My `models.py` look as follow:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '|' + str(self.author)
```

Defining the URL as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # re_path(r'^post/(?P<title>[\w\-]+)/$', PostView.as_view(), name='post_details'),
    path('post/<slug:title>', PostView.as_view(), name='post_details'),
]
```

and adding the following to the `views.py`:

```
class PostView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    slug_field = slugify('title')
    slug_url_kwarg = slugify('title')
    template_name = 'post_details.html'
```

resulted no success, as titles which have hyphens result a **Page not found (404)**. As seen from the `urls.py`, I have tried both using a regular expression and the newer Django 2.0+ syntax and both giving the same result.

Is my mistake in the URL definition or am I not introducing the slug correctly to the view?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, what i did is 
adding a porperty in the Model for slug.

```
@property
def slug(self):
    return self.title.replace(" ", "-")[:50]`
```

and in my 
`urls.py` :

```
path (r'^(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-_]+?)', PostView.as_view(), name='post_details'),
```

Comment: Don't you need `.lower()` in the property? And I still do not understand why my suggestion is not working.

Comment: what's the error that you have exactly to see if the problem is from urls.py or from the view

Comment: I am not getting any errors, just a 404 if the slug has hyphens in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on your models.py. It is also a best practice when implementing default page URLs.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'pk': self.id,
            'slug': self.slug
        }
        return reverse('post-pk-slug-title', kwargs=kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On your urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>-<str:slug>/', PostView.as_view(), name='post_details'),
```